# Retry a JPA transaction

Tags: jpa

Is there any way to retry a transaction that failed with a rollback exception in JPA? As far as I know all managed entities become detached if a transaction fails.

Basically what I want is: I load an entity, a user makes changes to that entity and afterwards persist the changes.

If the user makes valid changes everything works fine. But if the user makes an error and the transaction fails, they currently have to discard all the work, reload the entity, redo the work (without the error) and retry the transaction.

I tried to use a new EntityManager just for persisting basically like this:

```
    tmpEm = createEntityManager();
    final EntityObject find = tmpEm.findById(EntityObject.class, toPersistEntity.getId());
    if (find != null) {
      tmpEm.beginTransaction();
      tmpEm.merge(toPersistEntity);
      tmpEm.commitTransaction();
    } else {
      tmpEm.beginTransaction();
      tmpEm.persist(find);
      tmpEm.commitTransaction();
    }
```

but this does not always work, since EntityObject contains a OneToMany Collection, and I do not know if or which entities have been added (Well I could find it out, but that would require entity specific code for every entity that I can persist).

Is there a better way? Can I somehow return to the state the EntityManager was before beginning the transaction?

Comment: Your question is not clear. If the transaction failed, running the same code will fail again because you are doing the same operations. The only time a transaction can succeed in the second/third etc time is if the original transaction failed because some other transaction made a change that causes this transaction to fail. For example you are violating a unique key constraint, etc. Is the case?

Comment: The transaction fails because, two entities (one in the database and the one I'm trying to persist) have the same name, and the name has to be unique. In that case the transaction fails and the user should be able to change it and retry with a new name.

Comment: but in this case the client should call the method again, this time with another name, so it's not really a 'retry'. The entire operation is executed from scratch

Comment: it is not the same operation, 1 parameter has changed, true. But the point is that the entire operation CANNOT be executed from scratch, because all managed entities become detached.

Comment: That's my point exactly. You will have to invoke the entire operation again, fetch the relevant entities, merge/persist them and commit again. You cannot reuse the entities. Your client should catch the exception and handle it by invoking the operation again, with another name for example.